# Merging an entity inside an other entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, session-variables

I'm working with an entity Called "Session" kept in an HTTP Session.
This session is related to an Article, which is related to an Image. 
The problem is when i want to update this session by changing a simple datetime row. I Want to update it everytime i call an AJaX Request. When the article's image is not null, i got an error when flushing, somehow my image has become null. I have no idea how to handle this. When there's no image inside the Article, everything works.
And, somehow, when i call a "flush" in a totally random function, i got the error that my entity is invalid (" An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO photo..").

Here is the code i'm using to read and update my session.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$currentSession = $symfonySession->get('currentSession');

if($currentSession == null)
    return new Response(404);

$currentSession = $em->merge($currentSession);
$currentSession->setUpdated(new \Datetime());

$em->flush();
$em->detach($currentSession);

$symfonySession->set('currentSession', $currentSession);
```

Comment: I guess it's serialized so you need implement __wakeup, __sleep methods?

Comment: Do you mean i should make PHP to ignore the photo entity when comes to serialize ? Or to unserialize ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, i still have no idea how exactly it worked, but i only removed `cascade={"all"}`.